# Geolocation & Wordpress: best plugin for proximity search?

Tags: geolocation, wordpress

USE CASE

1. Search "Category" to find places near "Your address" (see form screenshot: http://o7.no/KYCj6v)
2. User gets a SERP like this:

   1,2 Miles - Italian Restaurant Pippo

   2,7 Miles - Chines Restaurant

   etc

QUESTION

Do you know of a an effective plugin to make this? That is: registering and resolving post addresses, resolving address inserted by user, calculating distances, producing a SERP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Www.geomywp.com does that and lot more

Comment: Thanks eyal, it looks really promising.